# Error java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opiejbc1

Tags: java, driver, mysql-connector

I'm having trouble accessing MySql from Java.

I'm using:

> **Operating system**: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux
> 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)
>
> **mysql**  Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
>
> javac 11.0.17

I use the following compilation line:

```bash
 javac -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar TestApplication.java

mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar is the mysql-connector.jar
```

I use the following line to execute:

java TestApplication

One of the lines produced by jar `tf /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar`

com/mysql/cj/jdbc/Driver.class

My source code:

```java
    import java.sql.*;

    public class TestApplication {
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opiejbc1";
       static final String USER = "opiejbc1";
       static final String PWD = "Linux@Me1";
       static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Test1";
       static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
   
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          // Open a connection
          try {
             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PWD);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);
             // Extract data from result set
             while (rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve by column name
                System.out.print("Name: " + rs.getInt("Name"));
                System.out.print(", Phone: " + rs.getInt("Phone"));
             }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }   
       }
    }
```

On execution I received:

```java
 java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opiejbc1
```

I've also tried the following:

```java
    import java.sql.*;

    public class TestApplication {
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opiejbc1";
       static final String USER = "opiejbc1";
       static final String PWD = "Linux@Me1";
       static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Test1";
       static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
   
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // Open a connection
          try {
             Class.forName(DRIVER);
             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PWD);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);
             // Extract data from result set
             while (rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve by column name
                System.out.print("Name: " + rs.getInt("Name"));
                System.out.print(", Phone: " + rs.getInt("Phone"));
             }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    }
```

On execution I receive the:

```java
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *javac -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar TestApplication.java* That's unnecessary at compile time. Only necessary at runtime. Get used to using try-with-resources for your java.sql objects

Comment: Check the command you use to execute the code. You did not share it.

Comment: mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar is the mysql-connector.jar

Comment: The line is use to execute is java TestApplication.

Comment: java -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar TestApplication causes the following error: Error: Could not find or load main class TestApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestApplication

Comment: Your classpath doesn't include your own code

Comment: adding my own code to the class path doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Show us what you did

Comment: java -cp /home/opiejbc1/java/TestApplication:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar TestApplication.class causes 
Error: Could not find or load main class TestApplication.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestApplication.class

Comment: java -cp /home/opiejbc1/java/TestApplication.class:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar TestApplication.class also causes                                                                                          Error: Could not find or load main class TestApplication.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestApplication.class

Comment: That's not a classpath. In which directory are your classes being placed? Does your code use packages?

Comment: I don't use a package. What do you mean by "That's not a  classpath."

Comment: My classes are in my current directory: /home/opiejbc1/java

Comment: If that's the path where TestApplication.class is, then your classpath is: `java -cp /home/opiejbc1/java:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar TestApplication`

Comment: Tried that with the same result.

Comment: Please post output of `ls -l /home/opiejbc1/java/TestApplication.class`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your [mysql connector jar](https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.zip) is on your classpath when running the code.

**Edit considering all the comments:**

If `java TestApplication` delivers `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, then try this from the same directory:

```
java -cp /home/opiejbc1/java:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector.jar:. TestApplication
```

Note the `:.` in the classpath.

Comment: mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar is the mysql-connector.jar